# T-SQL: Select ... where ID = one of a set of possible IDs

Tags: t-sql

I'll run through how the stored procedure functions now and get to the question after.  The current procedure accepts an ID number corresponding to a node within a tree - the ID is formatted such that the left substring of a child node contains the ID of its immediate parent.  So if a child node has the ID 10100349, then its parent has ID 101003.  The procedure returns any information belonging to the selected node and its children by the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[blah]

-- Parameter
@IDNumber varchar(100),

...

-- Get the length of the ID number
DECLARE @IDNumLength integer
SET @IDNumLength = LEN(@IDNumber)

...

SELECT
    *whatever information*
WHERE
    LEFT(table.[IDNumber], @IDNumLength) = @IDNumber
```

For illustrative purposes:

```
1010 (root node)
|
|_ 101001
|  |_ 10100101
|  |_ 10100102
|  |_ 10100103
|  |_ 10100104
|
|_ 101002
.  |_ 10100201
.  |_ 10100202
.  |_ 10100203
```

So searching for information on node 101001 would return information for itself and its child nodes 10100101 through 10100104.

This works fine for when only one ID is selected, but I'm trying to modify the query to accept multiple IDs so that the query returns information for multiple nodes.  The selected node IDs are passed in as a comma-delimited string ('101001,10100201,10100202') wherein none of the specified IDs are children of any other node in the string (this is done to avoid duplication of information - this condition is enforced prior to executing the query).

I've done some research into simulating arrays in T-SQL, but anything I've come across involves just searching on any elements in the "array".  The problem I'm stuck with is associating a length value with each ID similar to how the single-ID query is formed.

Thanks in advance.  If anyone has questions, I'll answer them as best as I can.

Comment: Your question is how to match elements in a comma-delimited list?  How to search hierachies?  Something else?

Comment: Question is how to match elements in a comma-delimited list, adhering to the WHERE condition at the top of the post.

Comment: If possible I'd recommend in using a HierarchyID (possibly in conjunction with the current setup) as it can make queries much easier .. Other alternatives for BOM-style queries include nested sets, as talked about by Joe Celko. `IN` is "the way" to search for value-set inclusion with DQL, but requires dynamic SQL to create such a clause. Other alternatives might including using a Table-Value [Function] and a Join. Consider including *which* version(s) of SQL Server is targeted ..

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of separation of concerns, so

First you might want to consider [parsing the string](http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-split-comma-delimited-string.html)
Second, Iterate through your list of strings 
   pass the a single value to your working sp, 
    return result to a temp table or table variable depending upon the circumstances.

finally process the completed results

Hope this helps!